# I created a Rock Paper Scissors (with tkinter) in object format but I can't display it [RESOLVED]

Tags: python, class, tkinter, random

Python tells me that I have an error in my canvas, even though I don't see any Here is the error message:

> PS C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Bureau\python\création_python\jeu_pfc> & "C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe" c:/Users/name/OneDrive/Bureau/python/création_python/jeu_pfc/jeu_pfc.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:\Users\name\OneDrive\Bureau\python\création_python\jeu_pfc\jeu_pfc.py", line 11, in 
> app.all()
>
> File "c:\Users\name\OneDrive\Bureau\python\création_python\jeu_pfc\classe.py", line 30, in all
> self.canvas.create_image(200/2, 200/2, image=self.image)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2847, in create_image

```py
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2833, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist
```

Here is my code:

```py
class rps():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.interface

    def interface(self):
        window = Tk()
        self.window = window
    
    def all(self):
        self.window.title("Rock Paper Or Scissors ?")
        self.window.iconbitmap("aopa.ico")
        self.window.geometry("1280x720")
        self.window.minsize(960, 720)
        self.window.config(background="#307ec7")
        self.window.configure(borderwidth=150)
        boite = Frame(self.window, bg="#307ec7")
        boite2 = Frame(boite, bg="#307ec7")
        
        self.image= PhotoImage(file="Lab.png").zoom(35).subsample(32)
        self.canvas = Canvas(boite, width=200, height=200, bg="#18153f",bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.create_image(200/2, 200/2, image=self.image)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.texte1 = Label(boite2, text="Rock Paper Or Scissors ?", bg="#3fc5bf", font=("Arials", 25), fg="#307ec7")
        self.texte1.pack()


        self.bouton1 = Button(boite2, text="Rock", font=("Arials", 20),command=self.Play_Rock_Paper_Scissors1)
        self.bouton1.pack()

        self.bouton2 = Button(boite2, text="Paper", font=("Arials", 20),command=self.Play_Rock_Paper_Scissors2)
        self.bouton2.pack()

        self.bouton3 = Button(boite2, text="Scissors", font=("Arials", 20),command=self.Play_Rock_Paper_Scissors3)
        self.bouton3.pack()

        self.texte2= Label(boite2, text="", bg="#3fc5bf", font=("Arials", 25), fg="#307ec7")
        self.texte2.pack()

        self.texte3= Label(boite2, text="", bg="#3fc5bf", font=("Arials", 25), fg="#307ec7")
        self.texte3.pack()

        boite.pack(expand=YES)
        boite2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

    
    def Play_Rock_Paper_Scissors1(self):
        a = self.bouton1.cget("text")
        choix_possibles = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        choice_of_AI = random.choice(choix_possibles)
        d = choice_of_AI
        self.texte2.configure(text="choice of AI : "+d)
        if (a == d):
            self.texte3.configure(text="equality")
        elif ((a == a and d == "Paper")):
            self.texte3.configure(text="AI won")
        else:
            self.texte3.configure(text="YOU WIN")

    def Play_Rock_Paper_Scissors2(self):
        b = self.bouton2.cget("text")
        choix_possibles = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        choice_of_AI = random.choice(choix_possibles)
        d = choice_of_AI
        self.texte2.configure(text="choice of AI : "+d)
        if (b == d):
            self.texte3.configure(text="equality")
        elif ((b==b and d=="Scissors")):
            self.texte3.configure(text="AI won")
        else:
            self.texte3.configure(text="YOU WIN")

    def Play_Rock_Paper_Scissors3(self):
        c = self.bouton3.cget("text")
        choix_possibles = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        choice_of_AI = random.choice(choix_possibles)
        d = choice_of_AI
        self.texte2.configure(text="choice of AI : "+d)
        if (c == d):
            self.texte3.configure(text="equality")
        elif ((c == c and d == "Rock")):
            self.texte3.configure(text="AI won")
        else:
            self.texte3.configure(text="YOU WIN")
```

second script :

```py
    from tkinter import *
    from classe import rps
    
    
    app = rps()
    
    
    app.interface()
    
    
    app.all()
    app.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error is mostly caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Also `mainloop()` should not be called inside `interface()` and `all()` since you have called `mainloop()` at the end of second script.

Comment: I removed the mainloop but now it gives me another error:   File "c:\Users\Name\OneDrive\Bureau\python\création_python\jeu_pfc\jeu_pfc.py", line 12, in <module>
    app.mainloop()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
    ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'rps' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: `app.mainloop()` should be `app.window.mainloop()` instead.  Also I wonder why `rps` inherits from `Frame` as you have never called the `Frame.__init__()` in your class `__init__()`.  Actually `rps` should not inherit from `Frame` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much now my problem is solved

Comment: @optik basique. Glad you solved problem.